# Cookie Expired Before Time And Saving in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

My server is GoDaddy. Server is using Pacific daylight time (-7:00). My cookie expiration is 15 minutes.

I see Current GMT Time is 5:35 AM Tuesday, 25 July 2023 Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) and time in server now is 10:35 PM, 24 July 2023

In my ASP.NET Core application when I set a cookie it sets a cookie, it sets as

```
_Gex.Application=chunks-2; expires=Tue, 25 Jul 2023 05:50:54 GMT;
```

But in browser this cookie is not saved in Chrome. If I increase the time to 2 days it works.

Answer (score 0):

We know that `DateTime.Now()` in `C#` gets the current server's time, and `Date()` in `Javascript` gets the client's time.

If the users visiting the site are from different time zones, then I think it is necessary to calculate the offset of the current user's device time from the service time.

We can get the current user time from the browser device through the Date() method when the user logs in, and we can add logic to calculate the offset in the login method, and create a new Claim and store it.

Then even if the user's device time is wrong, the cookie can expire after 15 minutes.

We can create a middleware that reads the offset of the time and sets the cookie expiration time.